# Возможно ли задать градиент в SVG от начала и до конца линии?

Tags: html, css, svg

Не понимаю, возможно ли не переворачивая направление градиента, задать его от точки начала отрезка до его конца? На примере в картинке градиент затрагивает как начало отрезка, так и конец.

```html
<svg
 width="210mm"
 height="297mm"
 viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
 version="1.1">
<g>
 <g>
  <path stroke="url(#gradient)"
   style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:8;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4.0999999;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
   d="m 30,452.3622 60,0 30,-30 70,0 30,30 55,0 60,60 0,240 -65,0 -30,30 -115,0"
   id="path7929-5"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccc" />

  <defs>
   <linearGradient id="gradient">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="red"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
  </defs>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Короткий ответ:*

нет

*Длинный ответ:*

По сути, вам нужно менять вектор направленности градиента, но согласно [спецификации](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradientElement) вектор задается двумя координатами, поэтому вращать его вдоль произвольной линии не получится.

В качестве альтернативы можно было бы поломать прямую с градиентом вдоль вашей линии, но в текущей спецификации (и скорее всего в текущих реализациях) этого пока нет (надеюсь, что только пока).